# Azure OAuth authentication failed to redirect after successful authentication with Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have .net core mvc application. I have implemented OAuth authentication with Azure AD for my web app.

From localhost it is working good as expected, but from Azure WebApp its failing to redirect to path after successful OAuth authentication.

FYI, I am accessing the application via AppGateway

I am using following code block for making OAuth Authentication.

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "ClientId": "567f20e2-eb4f-4a1b-8fe6-ff1d76be8ec0",
    "TenantId": "ea80952e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5457852b0f7e",
  },
```

I tried to define the redirect url in Azure App registration blade, but the defined values is not picking from the app.

[Azure App registration redirect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myEbj.png)

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Attached screenshot for your reference.
[Screenshot of error response after successful authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCBio.png)

Comment: Based on this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCBio.png), you have only set the redirect URI for your localhost. Where's the redirect URI for your cloud application?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this kind of problem, you can try a general solution:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. **Decode** the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl for your reply. I had some progress after assigning right value in appsettings for Azure.Domain property now I am getting redirected to appservice url. But app service is blocked and can't access without AppGateway. So I need to change the redirecturl to appgateway url. Could you please advice how to change the redirecturl from c# code?